# How to enable "Use build environment from another project" for a feestyle project using the Jenkins script console

Tags: jenkins

I have been skimming through most of the scripts at https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console but cannot find a way to enable the "Use build environment from another project" box on a freestyle project from the Jenkins script console.

Anybody with a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with a script similar to this:

```
import hudson.model.FreeStyleProject
import hudson.plugins.templateproject.ProxyBuildEnvironment
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

Jenkins.instance.items.each { item ->
    if (item instanceof FreeStyleProject) {
        item.buildWrappersList.replace(new ProxyBuildEnvironment('YourProject'))
        item.save()
    }
}
```